# How to stop or disable Google App Engine production server?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, google-apps

I have uploaded google app java project to production google app engine (from [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/uploading)), but I can't found any information how to stop or disable the production app engine.

From google developer console, I can shutdown the instance via menu Compute -> Instances, but if I open or access the app's url in the browser, the app instance will start running again.

So how to completely stop or disable Google App Engine production server?

Comment: you should decide if you are talking about Compute or App Engine :P

Comment: Paul Collingwood makes an excellent point

Comment: What is the difference between compute engine and app engine? I was following app engine tutorial btw.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Change you code to not serve pages and update the server online, or use the admin console and change the security settings so no one can see it.

i.e. go here.. 
https://appengine.google.com/ if you have a google app account then you should see that there's a "Disable or Delete Application" section.

Comment: Thanks, I have disabled it through menu Administration -> Application Settings. It seems the disable button has been removed in new console page. There is only delete project button in new developer console.

Comment: I'm curious, where is the security setting to disable view?

Comment: I have an appengine account.  When I go to https://appengine.google.com/ I see a list of apps.  Click on the one you want to disable.  Then the Application Settings menu, then Disable Application is on the page you get taken to.

Comment: Well, I already know about "Disable" button as I have mentioned in my 1st comment. What I mean is what you said about "change the security settings so no one can see it". I thought it's a different feature. Thx anyway.

Comment: It is.  Go to appengine, application settings, authentication type and set it to Google Apps Accounts
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/auth  
That will lock people out.  Which is not exactly what you asked for but achieves a similar thing.

Comment: I can't found "Google Apps Accounts" option there. In that article link, there is warning: "Currently, you cannot switch authentication options for existing App Engine apps to or from Google Apps Accounts. This option for restricting an application's authentication settings can only be set at or shortly after app creation time."

Comment: Oh. That does make sense.  Sorry.  I was looking at a recent project.

Answer (score 60):

Late to the game here, the tutorial currently suggests deleting the project, but I wanted to keep the project ID so the suggested option isn't the ideal solution for me.

After spending a good 15 min around the site I've found 2 ways to stop the application. Hope this will be of some help to others until the UI changes again.

## Method 1: Disable Application

Go into App Engine, Settings, click on **Disable application**.

[image: Screenshot of App Engine, Settings]

## Method 2: Stop Instance

Go into App Engine, Versions, and then click on **STOP**.

[image: Screenshot of App Engine, Versions]

Comment: Method 2 does not work. Stop is disabled and there is a tooltip saying that stop cannot be done for versions with manual or dynamic scaling.

Comment: You call method 2 "Stop instance" but you describe stopping a version and as @vap78 said it doesn't always work. You *can* stop the instance under "Instances" tab, but when there's a new request to the app, the instance will be started again (only in autoscaling?).

Comment: Does anybody know how much (or in what concepts) do you get charged even if it is disabled? Thanks

Comment: How can Method 1 be performed through glcoud CLI?

Answer (score 8):

For me none of the other solutions were applicable as I was testing AppEngine on a project that already used Firestore, and disabling the app would disable it as well which was not an option.
I contacted Google and this is the solution they gave me:

You can overwrite the default version of your app by redeploying the app with an empty application and create an app.yaml that uses only static files:

```
module: default
runtime: python27
api_version: '1.0'
threadsafe: true
handlers:
  - url: /
    static_files: index.html
    upload: index.html
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
```

a dummy index.html like:

```
<title>CLOSED</title>
```

and deploy it using:
`gcloud app deploy app.yaml`

Then you can stop your app using `gcloud app versions stop VERSION_ID`

Comment: This still costs "Backend Instance Hours".

This uses manual scaling instances, so App engine generates HTTP `/_ah/start` requests that end up creating generating "Backend Instance Hours".

Is this app free for you?

Comment: I haven't been billed since I did that

Comment: After stopping the service I was not billed actually.

Comment: I'd recommend `- url: /.*` because a simple `- url: /` for example won't necessarily kill your `/api/something` endpoint.

Answer (score 6):

Go into **App Engine** > **Instances**
Select all the **instances** you want to **delete**
Click on **delete**

[image]

Comment: it seems if you app is using the default Autoscale, if a new request comes in after deleting the instance, app engine spawns another instance...

Comment: This won't currently work with the default service type for your deployment