# Disable google app engine and keep compute engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a project and there is a GAE version deployed. I don´t use the App engine anymore although there are some Compute Engines running. How can I delete my app engine and keep my compute engines instance?

Under the version tabs the delete button is disabled.

[image]

Comment: Did you try the old console at https://appengine.google.com/?  Some things still work better there.

Comment: @Kekito Thanks, I tried as suggest by Jeffrey.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop or disable Google App Engine production server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27201832/how-to-stop-or-disable-google-app-engine-production-server)

Answer (score 2):

One thing you could do is upload a new empty instance and set it as the default.

Or use the old appengine admin console which can be found at appengine.google.com.  Find **Administration** > **Application Settings** > close to the bottom of the page there's the option to **Disable or Delete Application**

This still leaves the project accessible to the other products in the dev console.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Although I was not able to delete my application, because billing is enable. "You cannot request deletion since your app's Billing Status is Enabled." I can´t disable billing because will stop my compute engine instance =/

Comment: If you delete the GAE application, I'm afraid you won't have access to the GCE part as well since they both live under the same project id. Disabling it this way disables just the GAE component and leaves your GCE instances accessible. You need not worry about GAE being active for that project. It won't.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, but they charge for disabled application =/